# Android play ringtone using notification sounds in loop

Tags: android, notifications, ringtone

I have created a notification channel and added sound attributes to it.
The issue I am facing is that I am not able to loop the notification sound until the notification has been cancelled. I am using the flag **FLAG_INSISTENT**, with the `NotificationBuilder`, which as per the documentation, does the following -

> Bit set in the Notification flags field if the audio will be repeated until the notification is
>   cancelled or the notification window is opened.

This flag plays the sound in the loop but once notification window is opened(the notification panel is dragged down) the notification sound stops. Is there any alternative way to play the ringtone until the notification has been cancelled.

PS- I have explored other options such as `MediaPlayer` (which requires storage permission to play ringtone in external storage) and `Ringtone` object(this has the function of `setLooping()` which was added in API 28 and no alternative  for lower SDKs)